# $scope.my_model equivalent in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm newbie in angular2. Just want to know how to:

- read `[(ngModel)]` from view on the typescript controller side

Let say:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="my_model" />
```

Now, how I want to read the model value in my typescript controller?

The other one is how to set value of the `input` as `''` to my `[(ngModel)]`?

Example of codes:

View:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="my_model" />
<br/>
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Controller (Typescript)

```
submit(){
   ... //Then? if angularjs 1 just use $scope.my_model ...
   $scope.my_model = ''; //Only valid for angularjs1
}
```

Help me please... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components class is the model

```
submit() {
 this.my_model = ''
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I want to try...very fast response!

Comment: Do I need to declare such as `private my_model`? Since it shown error

Comment: Yes, I assumed you have that already because you use it in `[(ngModel)]="my_model"`. This is why I was wondering a bit what's the point of the question, but now it's clear :D